# Data source to ssas cube naming and numbering changing?

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

Our ssas cube transform both the language and the numbering from the original data source.

In our database our datetime view all cells containing "monday" as its "day name" attribute has the value "1" in its "day of the week" attribute.

[image]
Screenshot from ssms

But once this database containing this view is loaded into the ssas cube then the language is suddently changed from english to norwegian (Monday -> Mandag) and monday is now suddently the 7'th day in the week instead of 1st.

[image]
Screenshot from visual studio opening the cube bim

I have had a look at "translations" but nothing is selected - but somewhere it got to be changed since its changed within the cube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analysis Services has a feature for metadata translations (eg table and column names), but not for data translations.

> Translated strings are for object metadata only (names and
> descriptions of tables and columns) that appear in a client tool like
> an Excel PivotTable list. To use translated strings, the client
> connection specifies the culture. In the Analysis in Excel feature,
> you can choose the language from a drop-down list. For other tools,
> you might need to specify the culture in the connection string.
>
> This feature is not intended loading translated data into a model. If
> you want to load translated data values, you should develop a
> processing strategy that includes extracting translated strings from a
> data source that provides them.

[Translations in Tabular Models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/translations-in-tabular-models-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions)

So that's happening outside of SSAS.

Your database view probably returns data based on the connection's locale.  EG this

```
set language norwegian
select datename(dw,getdate())
```

outputs

```
Changed language setting to Norsk.

------------------------------
torsdag

(1 row affected)
```

Comment: Hi @David Browne,

This is interesting.

I'm unsure on how i disable / remove this "translation" - whenever i open visual studio with the concrete analysis project i don't find this translation anywhere.

The "translation folder" is completely empty.

I can't find any sql code or what so ever that implies that the data source or that the specific "view" is being transformed - yet "its"

Comment: See updated answer for possible explanation.

Comment: The answer from @David Browne was correct.

The view was made to have a -1 on the end of "day number of the week" because the database where the view are is set to usa.
Therefor the view returned mondag while being in usa-loc as the first day of the week while the correct should have been sunday.
The -1 was added as a solution to force monday as the first day of the week. 

However when the cube's norwegian location got its return from the view monday was forced by the -1 to be the last day of the week.

Removing the -1 in the view at the "day number of the week" line solved the issue.